# .Replace Errors from minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So all the `replace` lines are errored out and saying:

> The method `replace(char, char)` in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

I have tried everything but I can not get rid of the error.

```
package com.duckcraftpvp.enchants.Events.soul;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import com.duckcraftpvp.enchants.Events.SuccessAndDestroySystem;
import com.duckcraftpvp.enchants.RandomPackage;
import com.duckcraftpvp.enchants.RandomPackageAPI;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Effect;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.Sound;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.HumanEntity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Item;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerDropItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.server.PluginEnableEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.material.MaterialData;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;

public class soulEvents
  implements Listener
{
  public static ArrayList<Player> soulMode = new ArrayList();
  private ArrayList<Player> spam = new ArrayList();
private static HashMap<Player, Integer> soulGemSoulAmount = new HashMap();
  private static ItemStack soulModeItem = new ItemStack(Material.EMERALD, 1, (short)0);
  private static ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.ACACIA_STAIRS, 1);
  private static ItemMeta itemMeta = item.getItemMeta();
  private static ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList();
  private String type = null;
  private String typ3;

  @EventHandler
  private void soulGemDropSoulModeRemove(PlayerDropItemEvent event)
  {
    if ((event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType().equals(Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()))) && (event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getData().getData() == RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getInt("SoulGem.item-data")) && 
      (event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().hasItemMeta()) && (event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) && (event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getItemMeta().hasLore()) && 
      (event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getItemMeta().getLore().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getStringList("SoulGem.lore").toString()))) && 
      (soulMode.contains(event.getPlayer())))
    {
      soulMode.remove(event.getPlayer());
      for (int i = 0; i < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.deactivate").size(); i++) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', (String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.deactivate").get(i)));
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  @EventHandler
  private void soulTrackerApply(InventoryClickEvent event)
  {
    if ((event.getCurrentItem() == null) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) || (event.getCursor() == null) || (event.getCursor().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) || (!event.getCursor().getType().equals(Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers.item").toUpperCase()))) || 
      (!event.getCursor().hasItemMeta()) || (!event.getCursor().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) || (!event.getCursor().getItemMeta().hasLore()) || 
      (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("HELMET")) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("CHESTPLATE")) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("LEGGINGS")) || 
      (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("BOOTS")) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("HOE")) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().endsWith("SPADE")) || 
      (!SuccessAndDestroySystem.enchantableItems.contains(event.getCurrentItem().getType()))) {
      return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      if (i == 1) {
        this.type = "legendary";
      } else if (i == 2) {
        this.type = "ultimate";
      } else if (i == 3) {
        this.type = "elite";
      } else if (i == 4) {
        this.type = "unique";
      } else if (i == 5) {
        this.type = "simple";
      }
      if (event.getCursor().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".name"))))
      {
        item = event.getCurrentItem();
        itemMeta = item.getItemMeta();
        if ((item.hasItemMeta()) && (item.getItemMeta().hasLore()))
        {
          lore.addAll(item.getItemMeta().getLore());
          for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
          {
            if (j == 1) {
              this.typ3 = "legendary";
            } else if (j == 2) {
              this.typ3 = "ultimate";
            } else if (j == 3) {
              this.typ3 = "elite";
            } else if (j == 4) {
              this.typ3 = "unique";
            } else if (j == 5) {
              this.typ3 = "simple";
            }
            for (int o = 0; o < lore.size(); o++) {
              if (((String)lore.get(o)).startsWith(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.typ3 + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", ""))))
              {
                if (lore.contains(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore))
                {
                  lore.remove(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);lore.add(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);
                }
                lore.set(o, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", "0")));
                event.getWhoClicked().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("SoulTrackers.apply-" + this.type)).replace("%item%", event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().replace("_", " ")));
                finish(event);
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (lore.contains(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore))
        {
          lore.remove(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);lore.add(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);
        }
        lore.add(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", "0")));
        event.getWhoClicked().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("SoulTrackers.apply-" + this.type)).replace("%item%", event.getCurrentItem().getType().name().replace("_", " ")));
        finish(event);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  @EventHandler
  private void soulGemCombine(InventoryClickEvent event)
  {
    if ((event.getCurrentItem() == null) || (event.getCurrentItem().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) || (event.getCursor() == null) || (event.getCursor().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) || 
      (!event.getCursor().hasItemMeta()) || (!event.getCursor().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) || (!event.getCursor().getItemMeta().hasLore()) || (!event.getCurrentItem().hasItemMeta()) || (!event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) || (!event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().hasLore()) || 
      (!event.getCurrentItem().getType().equals(Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()))) || 
      (event.getCurrentItem().getData().getData() != RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getInt("SoulGem.item-data")) || 
      (!event.getCursor().getType().equals(Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()))) || 
      (event.getCursor().getData().getData() != RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getInt("SoulGem.item-data"))) {
      return;
    }
    Player player = (Player)event.getWhoClicked();
    if ((event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getLore().toString().equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getStringList("SoulGem.lore").toString()))) && 
      (event.getCursor().getItemMeta().getLore().toString().equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getStringList("SoulGem.lore").toString()))))
    {
      item = event.getCurrentItem();
      itemMeta = event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta();
      int soul1 = Integer.parseInt(ChatColor.stripColor(event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()).toLowerCase().replace("a", "").replace("b", "").replace("c", "").replace("d", "").replace("e", "").replace("f", "").replace("g", "").replace("h", "").replace("i", "").replace("j", "").replace("k", "").replace("l", "").replace("m", "")
        .replace("n", "").replace("o", "").replace("p", "").replace("q", "").replace("r", "").replace("s", "").replace("t", "").replace("u", "").replace("v", "").replace("w", "").replace("x", "").replace("y", "").replace("z", "").replace("`", "").replace("~", "").replace("!", "").replace("@", "").replace("#", "").replace("$", "").replace("%", "").replace("^", "").replace("&", "").replace("*", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "").replace("_", "")
        .replace("=", "").replace("+", "").replace("[", "").replace("{", "").replace("]", "").replace("}", "").replace("\\", "").replace("|", "").replace(";", "").replace(":", "").replace("'", "").replace("\"", "").replace(",", "").replace("<", "").replace(".", "").replace(">", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace(" ", ""));
      int soul2 = Integer.parseInt(ChatColor.stripColor(event.getCursor().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()).toLowerCase().replace("a", "").replace("b", "").replace("c", "").replace("d", "").replace("e", "").replace("f", "").replace("g", "").replace("h", "").replace("i", "").replace("j", "").replace("k", "").replace("l", "").replace("m", "")
        .replace("n", "").replace("o", "").replace("p", "").replace("q", "").replace("r", "").replace("s", "").replace("t", "").replace("u", "").replace("v", "").replace("w", "").replace("x", "").replace("y", "").replace("z", "").replace("`", "").replace("~", "").replace("!", "").replace("@", "").replace("#", "").replace("$", "").replace("%", "").replace("^", "").replace("&", "").replace("*", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "").replace("_", "")
        .replace("=", "").replace("+", "").replace("[", "").replace("{", "").replace("]", "").replace("}", "").replace("\\", "").replace("|", "").replace(";", "").replace(":", "").replace("'", "").replace("\"", "").replace(",", "").replace("<", "").replace(".", "").replace(">", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace(" ", ""));
      String color = null;
      for (int i = 100; i <= RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested; i += 100) {
        if ((Math.addExact(soul1, soul2) >= i) && (Math.addExact(soul1, soul2) < i + 100)) {
          color = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getPlaceholderConfig().getString("soul-gem." + i));
        }
      }
      if (Math.addExact(soul1, soul2) > RandomPackage.getPlaceholderConfig().getInt("max-soul-gem-souls-harvested"))
      {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("SoulGem.cannot-combine-above-max").replace("{MAX_SOULS}", RandomPackage.getPlaceholderConfig().getInt("max-soul-gem-souls-harvested")).replace("{PREFIX}", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_VILLAGER_NO, 1.0F, 2.0F);
      }
      else
      {
        itemMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", color + Math.addExact(soul1, soul2))));
        lore.addAll(event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getLore());
        finish(event);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
          player.getWorld().playEffect(player.getEyeLocation(), Effect.SPELL, 1);
        }
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_PLAYER_LEVELUP, 1.0F, 2.0F);
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  @EventHandler
  private void soulAdd(PlayerDeathEvent event)
  {
    if ((event.getEntity().getKiller() instanceof Player))
    {
      Player killer = event.getEntity().getKiller();
      if ((killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand() != null) && (!killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) && (killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().hasItemMeta()) && (killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().hasLore()))
      {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
          if (i == 1) {
            this.type = "legendary";
          } else if (i == 2) {
            this.type = "ultimate";
          } else if (i == 3) {
            this.type = "elite";
          } else if (i == 4) {
            this.type = "unique";
          } else if (i == 5) {
            this.type = "simple";
          }
          for (int o = 0; o <= RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested; o++) {
            if (killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", o))))
            {
              item = killer.getInventory().getItemInMainHand();
              if (item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() != null) {
                itemMeta.setDisplayName(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName());
              }
              lore.addAll(item.getItemMeta().getLore());
              lore.remove(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", o)));
              lore.add(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getGivedpItemsConfig().getString("SoulTrackers." + this.type + ".tracked-lore").replace("%souls%", Math.addExact(o, 1))));
              if (lore.contains(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore))
              {
                lore.remove(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);lore.add(RandomPackageAPI.whitescroll_apply_lore);
              }
              itemMeta.setLore(lore);
              item.setItemMeta(itemMeta);
              lore.clear();
              killer.getInventory().setItemInMainHand(item);
              killer.updateInventory();
              return;
            }
          }
        }
        return;
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  @EventHandler
  private void soulMode(final PlayerInteractEvent event)
  {
    if ((event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand() != null) && (!event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) && (event.getAction() != Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR) && (event.getAction() != Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK) && (event.getAction() != Action.PHYSICAL) && 
      (event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().hasItemMeta()) && (event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) && (event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().hasLore()) && (event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getData().getData() == RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getInt("SoulGem.item-data")))
    {
      int test = -1;
      for (int i = 1; i <= RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested; i++)
      {
        if (ChatColor.stripColor(event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()).equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", i))))) {
          test = i;
        }
        if ((test == -1) && (i == RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested)) {
          return;
        }
      }
      if (Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()) == null)
      {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(RandomPackage.prefix + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Invalid material for Soul Gem. '" + ChatColor.RED + RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item") + ChatColor.YELLOW + "'");
        event.getPlayer().playSound(event.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_VILLAGER_NO, 1.0F, 2.0F);
        return;
      }
      if (!soulMode.contains(event.getPlayer()))
      {
        if (event.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", "0"))))
        {
          if (!this.spam.contains(event.getPlayer()))
          {
            this.spam.add(event.getPlayer());
            event.getPlayer().playSound(event.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_VILLAGER_NO, 1.0F, 1.0F);
            for (int i = 0; i < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.need-souls").size(); i++) {
              event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', ((String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.need-souls").get(i)).replace("%prefix%", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
            }
            Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(RandomPackage.getPlugin(), new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                soulEvents.this.spam.remove(event.getPlayer());
              }
            }, 20L);
            return;
          }
          return;
        }
        soulMode.add(event.getPlayer());
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.activate").size(); i++) {
          event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', ((String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.activate").get(i)).replace("%prefix%", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
        }
      }
      else
      {
        soulMode.remove(event.getPlayer());
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.deactivate").size(); i++) {
          event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', ((String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.deactivate").get(i)).replace("%prefix%", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
        }
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  @EventHandler
  private void soulModeTimings(PluginEnableEvent event)
  {
    if (Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()) != null)
    {
      int data = 0;
      if (RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().get("SoulGem.item-data") != null) {
        data = RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getInt("SoulGem.item-data");
      } else {
        data = 0;
      }
      soulModeItem = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.item").toUpperCase()), 1, (byte)data);
    }
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(RandomPackage.getPlugin(), new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < soulEvents.soulMode.size(); i++)
        {
          if (!Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getWorld().getGameRuleValue("sendCommandFeedback").equals(Boolean.valueOf(true))) {
            Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getWorld().setGameRuleValue("sendCommandFeedback", "false");
          }
          Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "execute " + Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getName() + " ~ ~ ~ particle enchantmenttable " + Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getLocation().getX() + " " + Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getLocation().getY() + " " + Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getLocation().getZ() + " .5 .5 .5 1 100 1");
        }
      }
    }, 0L, 5L);
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(RandomPackage.getPlugin(), new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < soulEvents.soulMode.size(); i++) {
          for (int o = 0; o < Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getSize(); o++) {
            if ((Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o) != null) && (!Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getType().equals(Material.AIR)) && 
              (Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).hasItemMeta()) && (Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) && 
              (Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getType().equals(soulEvents.soulModeItem.getType())) && 
              (Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getData().equals(soulEvents.soulModeItem.getData())))
            {
              if (ChatColor.stripColor(Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getItemMeta().getDisplayName()).equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", "0")))))
              {
                for (int p = 0; p < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.out-of-souls").size(); p++) {
                  Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', ((String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.out-of-souls").get(p)).replace("%prefix%", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
                }
                soulEvents.soulMode.remove(i);
                return;
              }
              for (int p = 1; p <= RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested; p++) {
                if (ChatColor.stripColor(Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o).getItemMeta().getDisplayName()).equalsIgnoreCase(ChatColor.stripColor(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", p)))))
                {
                  soulEvents.item = Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().getItem(o);
                  String color = "";
                  for (int z = 100; z <= RandomPackageAPI.getAvailableMaxSoulGemSoulsHarvested; z += 100) {
                    if ((Math.subtractExact(p, 1) >= z) && (Math.subtractExact(p, 1) < z + 100)) {
                      color = RandomPackage.getPlaceholderConfig().getString("soul-gem." + z);
                    }
                  }
                  soulEvents.itemMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getSoulConfig().getString("SoulGem.name").replace("%souls%", color + Math.subtractExact(p, 1))));
                  if (soulEvents.item.getItemMeta().hasLore()) {
                    soulEvents.lore.addAll(soulEvents.item.getItemMeta().getLore());
                  }
                  soulEvents.itemMeta.setLore(soulEvents.lore);
                  soulEvents.item.setItemMeta(soulEvents.itemMeta);
                  soulEvents.lore.clear();
                  soulEvents.soulGemSoulAmount.remove(Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()));
                  soulEvents.soulGemSoulAmount.put(Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()), Integer.valueOf(p));
                  Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).getInventory().setItem(o, soulEvents.item);
                  if ((RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getBoolean("SoulMode.soul-drain-message")) && (
                    (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("00")) || (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("10")) || (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("20")) || 
                    (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("40")) || (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("60")) || (Integer.toString(Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).endsWith("80")))) {
                    for (int q = 0; q < RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.soul-drain-update").size(); q++) {
                      Bukkit.getPlayer(((Player)soulEvents.soulMode.get(i)).getName()).sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', ((String)RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getStringList("SoulMode.soul-drain-update").get(q)).replace("%souls%", Math.subtractExact(p, 1)).replace("%prefix%", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', RandomPackage.getMessagesConfig().getString("prefix")))));
                    }
                  }
                  return;
                }
              }
              return;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, 0L, 20L);
  }

  public static void finish(InventoryClickEvent event)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
      if ((item.hasItemMeta()) && (item.getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) && (item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains(RandomPackageAPI.transmog.replace("%loreCount%", i)))) {
        itemMeta.setDisplayName(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().replace(RandomPackageAPI.transmog.replace("%loreCount%", i), Math.addExact(i, 1)));
      }
    }
    itemMeta.setLore(lore);
    item.setItemMeta(itemMeta);
    event.setCurrentItem(item);
    if (event.getCursor().getAmount() > 1) {
      event.getCursor().setAmount(event.getCursor().getAmount() - 1);
    } else {
      event.setCursor(new ItemStack(Material.AIR));
    }
    event.setCancelled(true);
    ((Player)event.getWhoClicked()).updateInventory();
    lore.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Read the error, it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Lol, I have tried that. Alot of times. Nothing works. I cant change it to a char or string. has to be a int.

Comment: Why does it have to be? Read the JavaDocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: Also i dont see a error code on this site.

Comment: Only use code snippets for runnable Java*Script* /HTML/CSS code... use regular code formatting for others

Comment: thanks for editing that xD

Comment: Also i am a new java programmer so idk alot. This code is from someone who quit and im trying to fix it and make it work.

Comment: My advice: Learn Java before learning a library such as Bukkit

Answer (score -1):

To solve your error, you can do the following:

The replace method only accept (charSequence toReplace, charSequence replacement) as parameters. You can easily add your int to be replace on the method, doing the following:

```
int i = 0;
String iString = String.valueOf(i);
```

String.valueOf(int i) converts the int i to a String form, making it a CharSequence. That way you can use the replacemethod with your integer.